# phantom breakpoint driving me crazy!

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints

I have no idea where it came from, it doesn't show up in my breakpoitns view, but every time I start my program, before it gets to my code it breaks at the beginning of FileInputStream.class

It's just getting really annoying.  I am using eclipse 3.4 and java 1.6.
Thanks!
Joshua

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my Eclipse project have phantom debugger breakpoints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723199/why-does-my-eclipse-project-have-phantom-debugger-breakpoints)

Answer (score 11):

Did you check [Why does my Eclipse project have phantom debugger breakpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723199/why-does-my-eclipse-project-have-phantom-debugger-breakpoints) ?

More specifically the
"`Window > Preferences > Java > Debug : Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions`"
option.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar behavior in µVision for embedded system once. Is there some command like "Kill all breakpoints"? It helped me alot. 
Perhaps you have some configuration for that class in your IDE?(right click on that class?)

Regards
Sascha

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to open a file or some other input device and got exception. Thats the reason Eclipse behaves like there is a breakpoint.