# Prevent xdebug to break at first line of index file

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug, break, eclipse-pdt

I have xdebug setup with Eclipse PDT. Every time I start a debug session, Eclipse breaks at the first line of my root index.php file. Is it possible to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Ok I found what the problem was. In Eclipse, I just needed to go in "Windows -> Preferences -> PHP -> Debug" and uncheck "Break at first line".

To make it work, I also had to go in "Run > Debug Configurations > PHP Web Application" and unselect "Break at first line" in all the configurations.

You might have to restart Eclipse for it to work.

Comment: Thank you.  The "Run > Debug Configurations > PHP Web Application" was not obvious to me

Comment: I also found one more setting on "Project > Properties > PHP > Debug", unselect "Break at First Line"

Comment: Why is this even active by default!

Comment: I am using XDebug Chrome plugin and I am not starting the project directly from Eclipse. I had to restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

This question is orginated from eclipes. But the title took me to this page when i'm searching for this issue.

So for beneficial of the community, anyone who is using **netbeans**, you can do this by `tool` -> `options`

[image]