# Eclipse pausing without a breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

While debugging my project in Eclipse, it will (repeatably, at the same point in the code) pause execution as if it's reached a breakpoint.  No exceptions are thrown, the project has no breakpoints, and if I hit resume, it carries on without a problem.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723199/why-does-my-eclipse-project-have-phantom-debugger-breakpoints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Eclipse debugger pauses if the code throws an exception - at least it does for me (maybe this can be toggled). Just un-pause the thread and you'll most likely see a stacktrace being printed to STDERR.

[image]

Comment: For me unchecking first checkbox i.e. "Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions" worked. Much a relief !!!

Answer (score 5):

Your code and the binaries that you are debugging are not in sync.
Try creating a break point and then getting rid of all breakpoints and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem I apparently had some hidden breakpoints, setting a new one then clearing all break points solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Remove all breakpoints` from the `Breakpoints` view (hidden by default, `Window` > `Show view` > `Other...` > `Debug` > `Breakpoints`).

This solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a fresh workspace and import your project to this newly created workspace. The problem should be gone, especially if the problem was caused by corrupt workspace metadata.

Answer (score 0):

it could also be waiting for user input, or a particular action to take place so it can continue.