# Eclipse pausing without a breakpoint on getting session code

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, debugging, breakpoints

While debugging, my Eclipse pause on same line every time. I read this [Eclipse pausing without a breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441153/eclipse-pausing-without-a-breakpoint), but there are no exceptions in my console. I also read this [Why does my Eclipse project have phantom debugger breakpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723199/why-does-my-eclipse-project-have-phantom-debugger-breakpoints), but it doesn't help too.

The code that pauses debugger without breakpoint is this:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
```

I think there's no problem with `createQuery()`. Whenever `getCurrentSession()` called, my Eclipse pauses. Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you try terminating all running consoles and recompiling?

Comment: @Gnon Yes, I tried, but didn't work.

Comment: Does it indicate why it paused in the stack?  Are there entries in the Breakpoints view that you're not expecting?

Comment: @nitind There are no breakpoints in the Breakpoints view. And what do you exactly mean the stack? There's nothing in console.

Comment: The Debug view.  If it's pausing, you should be shown the stack of the paused thread, hopefully with some indication of *why* it paused.

Comment: @nitind I don't know why but it doesn't happen anymore. It's mysterious. If it happens again, I'll check that stack. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I face this kind of problem and everytime I end up finding out that my java code is not synchronized with my .class, this happens when I'm in remote debugging. Try to close your eclipse, clean your project and then try again. If you're debugging remotely, update your source codes.

Cheers!

Comment: try to debug a different project. If you face the same problem, maybe you should start thinking of downloading a brand new eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Look into concurrency. Maybe ur running into situations like deadlock. It happens when two objects are not locked in the same order, causing two different threads to be waiting for each other to release other object.

At this point it appears that the entire program has paused. Maybe its whats happening, but cant say for sure until I can see the code.

Comment: No, the program is ok. There are no problems except pausing while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Application always multithreading.. Obvously that application stop in another thread. When you analyze on which tread Eclipse stop and click on this thread - you found that Eclipse starts to react on command.