# Debug hit without breakpoint - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am debugging certain project and put debug point at a location in eclipse.

But, execution pauses somewhere I have not put debug point.

I googled it but of not help. [referred here also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441153/eclipse-pausing-without-a-breakpoint) and tried everything, again of no use.

*Snapshots :*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Break-on-exception is set, and something's throwing an NPE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer to my query, thanks to comment by Chrylis.

*Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug*

Uncheck *Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions*.

[image]