# How do I get rid of phantom breakpoints in javascript files in Aptana?

Tags: javascript, debugging, breakpoints, aptana

I have a small project containing 1 HTML file and 4 JavaScript files. Recently, while debugging my scripts using the Aptana Firefox plugin, I managed to introduce what I'll call a 'phantom' breakpoint into my project.

The breakpoint itself is tied to a particular line, not a particular expression or call. For example, if the 'phantom' breakpoint is affecting line 79 and I have only a comment on line 79, the breakpoint is never hit. But, if I have a valid JavaScript statement, such as 'var x = 2;' on line 79, the breakpoint will always be hit.

Re-adding the breakpoint on that line and removing using the 'Remove' command in the Breakpoints view does nothing.

Clearing all breakpoints through the 'Run->Remove all breakpoints' option does nothing.

The breakpoint does not show up in the Breakpoints view, and there is no indication in the file that the breakpoint exists.

I have tried deleting my workspace and recreating. Didn't work.

I have tried deleting the project and re-adding the source files. Didn't work.

I have verified that the breakpoint is not an unhandled exception as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723199/why-does-my-eclipse-project-have-phantom-debugger-breakpoints).

Does anyone know how to remove these 'phantom' breakpoints from Aptana projects?

Environment:
Windows 7 64-bit
Aptana Studio v2.0.5
Aptana Debugger Firefox plugin v1.6.0 
Firebug plugin v1.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Start debugger session from Aptana Studio
2. Switch to Firefox, open Firebug using status bar icon.
3. Open Breakpoints tab on right
4. In it's drop-down menu select "Remove All Breakpoints"

Comment: Thanks @Max. That worked perfectly. I knew the breakpoints weren't being stored by aptana, but it never occurred to me to check the Firebug plugin.

Comment: The option is grayed out and there's like 5 ghost breakpoints that trigger when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way I found which will get rid of this type of breakpoint is:
Click on firebug icon in the actual page, and select options and click reset all firebug options.

That should take care of this issue.