# Surfacelayer is not in the purgatory list

Tags: android, logcat

If I watch the LogCat while I run my Android app I get the message `SurfaceLayer is not in the purgatory list`. The app doesn't crash, but it is there all the time and I want to fix it.

There aren't very many posts about this, but here: [Hangup in ActivityThread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010349/hangup-in-activitythread) they discuss it a bit. One should disable "stop execution" on hidden breakpoints. But my app doesn't stop. It just shows something is wrong.

I am trying to give my Logcat a spring clean and this is the dirt in the middle of the floor.
Thankful for any ideas!