# Purgatory list Error (in LogCat)

Tags: android, list, logcat, surfaceflinger

Is anyone familiar with the following error in LogCat?

`10-21 19:45:42.476: E/SurfaceFlinger(155): layer=0x7486e0 is not in the purgatory list`

I read up on "SurfaceFlinger", which seems to be responsible for graphics rendering on Android, but I'm struggling to find any documentation that covers what a purgatory list is. One other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241646/surfacelayer-is-not-in-the-purgatory-list) had a referred to a similar error (but they didn't get a response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purgatory list [went away](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/6710604286401d4205c27235a252dd0e5008cc08) in Android 4.3 (API 18).  As near as I can tell the error associated with the message you're seeing was simply ignored.

The list was part of a cleanup mechanism used when graphical layers are destroyed (possibly to avoid destroying a buffer that's still being composited).  I think the error means that somebody requested deletion of a layer that has already been deleted -- could be a race somewhere.  If you're seeing some odd behavior it's possible this is related, but it's also likely that you can safely ignore this.