# Why do I have unknown breakpoints showing in my Markers tab?

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints

There are two "Unknown" items in my Markers tab for "Java Exception Breakpoints".

[image: Snapshot of Markers tab in Eclipse]

Any ideas what they are, and how I can get rid of them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a better solution to the same problem: 
[Remove java exception breakpoints when debugging Liferay in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531925/remove-java-exception-breakpoints-when-debugging-liferay-in-eclipse/11534562#11534562)

A more detailed explanation of why this happens ishere: [Why does my Eclipse project have phantom debugger breakpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723199/why-does-my-eclipse-project-have-phantom-debugger-breakpoints?rq=1)

I found the above after I deleted the unknown Java Exception Breakpoints (as advised above) and they reappeared. In my case it was for an OFBiz project in Eclipse Juno.

Answer (score 27):

To get rid of them, right click and select delete...

You can also right click and select Go To, or if that is not available, Show in properties which will give more info.

Comment: I figured that just hid some underlying issue. Do you know why they appear? The `Go To` menu item is disabled.

Comment: @Jeremy I don't know, but I don't think its cause for concern. My best guess is that sometimes when in debugging mode, an exception will be thrown and the debugger will pause execution to allow you to inspect it (IE, an NPE or IndexOutOfBounds), a breakpoint might be inserted then to allow that. but thats just a guess.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler What Go To menu? Where to enable them back?