# Remove java exception breakpoints when debugging Liferay in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, liferay, xdebug, liferay-ide

By debugging of Liferay Portal, that is tomcat application, eclipse make usual stop at `ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 912` although I don't set a breakpoint at this class. The `ThreadPoolExecutor` isn't a class of my application, I think that belongs to tomcat. My Question is: what is wrong here, and why eclipse stopt here?
And is it possible to set such "external breakpoints" in eclipse to ignore?

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can fix this immediately by opening the Markers view and delete the Java Exception Breakpoints.

[image: Markers view with Java Exception Breakpoints]

However, to permanently remove this type of breakpoints, you have to go to the Java Debug options and uncheck the "Suspend excecution on uncaught exceptions" option. Then this type of breakpoints won't get added again in the future.

[image: Java Debug options in Eclipse]

Comment: Unchecking "Suspend execution on uncaught exception" does not prevent those breakpoints from showing up. However, deleting them works till the next time your restart eclipse.

Comment: Even after deleting, it reappears once i restart eclipse. Is there anyway to delete permanantly?