# Eclipse java Exception Breakpoint (2 items)

Tags: eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

In Eclipse EE Luna i have java exception breakpoint.I have also installed a Spring plugin (Spring tool suite)

[image]

If i click on Show in/Properties i have this

[image]

Why do I have this error?Do you know why they appear?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this by also setting an exception breakpoint, but I don't see those entries in the Markers view. Can you provide steps how to reproduce this?

Comment: Yesterday I installed eclipse for the first time and I had not created any project..Although there was no project appeared to me these errors.I have only created two server:glassfish and tomcat

Comment: I downloaded a fresh Eclipse Luna JEE release build and installed it, but as long as I don't have a project I am not able to set those Java Exception breakpoints. How do you do that?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the path or classpath and the location of the workspace..In windows 7 I set the path but not the classpath

Comment: please also keep in mind to not install STS into the "Program Files" area, since that is a very restricted environment. You can also check the installed JREs in STS itself by going to the preferences, the Java category, and select the "Installed JREs" to see if everything is configured correctly inside STS.

Comment: Eclipse works fine, but I still have these two errors..Eclipse is installed on the desktop.Workbench is in C:\Utente\workspace , JAVA_HOME C:\glassfish4\jdk7 and PATH C:\glassfish4\jdk7\bin

Comment: do you see those breakpoints in the breakpoints view in the debug perspective? And if so, can you delete them there?

Comment: Just delete the `Java Exception Breakpoint` marker. And it won't appear again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my Eclipse project have phantom debugger breakpoints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723199/why-does-my-eclipse-project-have-phantom-debugger-breakpoints)

Answer (score 0):

It may be a permission issue of Eclipse workspace directory on Win7 or Win10.
Try to set write permission of workspace directory to Everyone/Users, or run Eclipse as Administrator.